# Matlab tickmarks outside (not inside) axis box

Tags: matlab, plot

Is there a way to extend tickmarks to the outside of the axis, or to generally display them on the outer side of an axis. In my histogramm

[image]

you can't really notice the tickmarks on the X-axis because of the edgecolor of the bars. That's why I would like to extend them a little bit towars the numbers below.

I know it should be possible to draw some extra-lines on top of the axis but is there a quicker way doing this??

Answer (score 9):

You can use `set(gca, 'TickDir', 'out')`. A complete reference of axes properties can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html).

***Edit.***
There is no straightforward way to apply a tick direction to one axis only.
Here's a semi-hack that uses two axes-objects, one for each axis:

```
plot([1 2 3], [1 2 3]);
h1 = gca;
h2 = copyobj(h1, gcf);
set(h1, 'TickDir', 'out', 'YTick', []);
set(h2, 'XTick', []);
```

Comment: Is there a way to just adress the X-Axis??? I checked the manual but couldn't find out if there is a specific handle for that.